# Manually Striping Bootstrap Table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I like the way the `table-striped` class shades every other row in my table.

But I have a need to shade groups of rows. Is there an easy way (preferably with CSS and no JavaScript) to apply the same shading to individual rows myself?

For example, I'm showing a daily menu, and I want to highlight every food within the same meal the same.

Comment: Doesn't `.table-striped` just add a `#f9f9f9` background on that tr? Why don't you just copy the style you want and add a custom class to the rows you want to highlight?

Comment: Sure, I could do that. But I would prefer not to hard code colors in case I change them later. Also, I think Bootstrap actually sets the colors of the individual table cells, so I'm not sure that's a good approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [**Contextual classes**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables-contextual-classes) of bootstrap:

`.active` - Applies the hover color to a particular row or cell

`.success`    Indicates a successful or positive action

`.info`     Indicates a neutral informative change or action

`.warning`  Indicates a warning that might need attention

`.danger`       Indicates a dangerous or potentially negative action

Or you can create new classes of your own with custom colors.. for e.g.

`.lunch{ background:orange; }`

And just give this class to any relevant row in your table:

```
....
<tr class="lunch">...</tr>
....
```

Comment: Yeah, adding "active" to the row classes seems to do what I need. Thanks.